# xls mail can't be previewed in iOS mail app

Tags: ios, xls, email-attachments

I have written an BackUp app for iPhone contacts which sends an xls attached mail to the specified mail address...

in early days of my coding, when the app sends the xls file, in which the contacts exist, I can preview it through the mail app in iOS.

now, i finished coding, but the sent xls file, cant be previewed in the iOS mail app... i also tried to preview it in Outlook. it is again same... in Outlook, i can open the file when i pressed on it, but when i select preview, it cant be opened...

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how the XLS file is being created if you can't preview it in either iOS or Outlook. How are you creating your XLS file? Always include your source code in your posts, as it's impossible to identify what the issue is with your code without seeing it.